# what do the numbers in VERSIONs mean?

Tags: versioning

I mean for example if a software has this number in its version 13.0.5 and another version has 13.0.5.1 or something like that what is that zero for?what does this zero show?
Is there a rule for these numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it appear because there is a revision number after it. If it's been 13.0.0 then that'll be 13.0 . Major and Minor revision must always show, but the revision and build number are not mandatory.

That said, there's many ways to manage version numbers.

This should help you figure out : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning

Hope that help.

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia reference from Marc on [Software Versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) is good,
and you might also like to read Jeff's post on [What's In a Version Number, Anyway?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/whats-in-a-version-number-anyway.html).
While we are at this, the [Ubuntu scheme](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames) is fun and neat too.

Comment: "quite interesting"? no.  "confusing as hell"? yes.  who uses datecodes in software versions?  nobody else!  nobody can remember "9.04" and "9.10"; they all remember "9.1" and "9.4"! (and guess which one they think comes first?)  arrrrrrrrgh!!!  `</rant>`

Comment: At least it's consistent, whereas Microsoft can't decide what to do: 3.1, 95, 98, ME, 2000, XP, Vista, 7 ...imagine if they released a new version every six months!

Comment: @brian: at least ubuntu's codenames make it easy to remember the ordering.  quick quiz: which came first, Tiger or Panther?

Comment: @Quack, Actually most people I know refer to Lucid as ten-four and Karmic as nine-ten `:-)`

Comment: roger roger. ten-four, good buddy.  *(what??)*  erm.  i must be fixing too many typos around here then.  grr.

Answer (score 1):

[What do the numbers in a version typically represent (i.e. v1.9.0.1) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65718/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-version-typically-represent-i-e-v1-9-0-1)
"1 - Major Revision ... 9 - Minor Revision ... 0 - Bug Fixes ... 1 - Build number (if used) ... "

[How to do version numbers - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615227/how-to-do-version-numbers)
"[major].[minor].[release].[build]"

[Version numbering basics - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889615/version-numbering-basics)
"Major Release.Minor Release.Hot Fix.Build"

Answer (score 0):

Or modern style

Version 1
Version 2
Version 3
Version 3.1
Version 95
Version ZZXXYY
Version cool_name
Version cute_name
Version 2010
Version 8
Version super gold turbo ninja enterprise edition 
(at this point they are bought out by a competitor and disappear)